# How to prevent page refresh after file save using filesaver.js and canvas-toBlob.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, filesaver.js

I have implemented a little function in js/jquery to create a save file button, allowing users to save a chart made in chart.js to their system. However, when the button is clicked, the page refreshes and returns to the top. I've reviewed the rest of my code and found nothing else that would cause this to happen. How can I prevent this behavior?

The function is below; the chart is constructed using the standard chartjs object. The site is built with bootstrap 4.

```
$('#save-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#printBarChart').get(0).toBlob(function(blob) {
        saveAs(blob, "combined_bar_chart.png");
    });
});
```

Comment: Show all the code

Comment: Nevermind, that probably won't help.  I think the was filesaver handles the download makes this difficult.

Comment: I have the same issue, didi you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You might try preventDefault() on that click

Should be

```
$('#save-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#printBarChart').get(0).toBlob(function(blob) {
        saveAs(blob, "combined_bar_chart.png");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, `e.preventDefault()` really prevents refreshing after call to `saveAs`

Answer (score -1):

For TS Angular, revert:

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver'
```

to

```
import FileSaver from 'file-saver'
```

Comment: Question is regarding `jQuery` not `Angular`

Comment: @Zaheer Are you saying jQuery can't be used in an Angular application, and this dependancy call, cause the a page refresh..?